# Setting up JupyterLab with multiple python kernels on Windows using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I'm finding myself always having trouble when creating a new conda environment and adding it to the jupyter kernels.

I follow the official documentation for [creating a new env](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) and [adding it to jupyter kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). This boils down to the following code:

```
SET new_env_name="mynewenv"
SET new_env_libs=python>3.7 pandas matplotlib scipy bokeh=2

conda create --yes -n %new_env_name% ipykernel %new_env_libs%
conda activate %new_env_name%
python -m ipykernel install --user --name %new_env_name% --display-name %new_env_name%
```

They are usually 2 errors with the following libraries' DLLs:

- **pyzmq**

> File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs...\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import (constants, error, message, context,
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

- **numpy**

  > ~\anaconda3\envs...\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in 
  >     6 
  >   ----> 7 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  >     8     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)
  >   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The second one has also a bit more description and some hints on how to solve it (see [relevant github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14770))

And the solutions I found always seem to suggest **reinstalling with pip** and/or **installing an older version**. Which I usually achieve by running: `pip install pyzmq numpy --force` on the activated new enviroment.

This seems a bit hacky. Does anyone know if there is a better way to solve these issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want to make sure I understand things correctly, you're trying to create a kernel such that you can use it in another environment?

Comment: yes, the each kernel should be linked to a different conda environment. So that when opening jupyter lab I have a few environment to chose from.

Comment: I use a similar setup. I'm on Windows Server 2016. I edited the .bashrc for my git bash shortcut to start run conda.sh on startup so i have a git bash and conda in the same terminal. i use a single conda environment for jupyterlab and then have kernels setup for all my other conda env's (project specific). I encounter the numpy dll error any time one of my project conda env's use a python version over 3.6.7. Definitely frustrating.